# Tools to clone a RHEL or FreeBSD box like SuperDuper does on Mac?

Tags: macos, clone, freebsd, rhel

I maintain a couple of boxes that run Mac OS X Server. One of the great things about it is that I can use SuperDuper! to clone volumes. For example, I can take a snapshot of the entire boot volume before I apply software updates, and if something goes horribly wrong I can roll back to the snapshot. Or I can clone to an external drive and then swap in higher-powered hardware.

I also use SuperDuper to clone my MacBook drive to an external drive, and if my internal drive goes boom I can just boot from the external drive and keep working.

I imagine that a tool like this must exist for Linux or FreeBSD, too. How would one go about taking snapshots of a Linux box that is running right on the hardware (nonvirtualized)?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using LVM in Linux then you can snapshot a volume by running `lvcreate -L15G -s -n mysnapshot /home/user/volume`.  HowtoForge has a great tutorial on [LVM Snapshots](http://www.howtoforge.com/linux_lvm_snapshots).

If you are using ZFS on FreeBSD or Linux (via fuse) then it is easy as running 'zfs snapshot tank/test@DATE'.  See the [FreeBSD ZFS Wiki](http://wiki.freebsd.org/ZFS) page for more information.